# Render HTML in Vue.js Grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, vue.js, render

I'm currently looking at the following example: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/examples/grid-component.html

and my goal is to have the data be HTML that is rendered. Here's what I've tried:

```
// bootstrap the demo
var demo = new Vue({
el: '#demo',
data: {
    searchQuery: '',
    gridColumns: ['html'],
    gridData: [
        { html: '{{{<html><div><p>test</p></div></html>}}}', name: 'Chuck Norris', power: Infinity },
        { name: '<html><div><p>test</p></div></html>', power: 9000 },
        { name: '<div v-html="<p>Test</p>"></div>', power: 7000 },
    ]
}
});
```

This is a proof of concept before I clean up the other data points. The requirements call for having a single-column grid that has boxes as it's items, with each box being a snapshot of rendered HTML.

We don't want to have to render the HTML to images if possible. In production, the HTML will be the content html of email mailings. Everything else, code wise, is the same as the example posted in the above link.

Thanks

Comment: Looks like components should solve your problem, https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html

Comment: I agree with @StefanE - registering your own custom component will solve this easily.

Comment: I dnn't think that this work `'{{{<html><div><p>test</p></div></html>}}}'` with v-html because the curly brackets have to be interpreted by themself.